# How to quote exclamation marks in file names in a tcsh shell script with find and awk?

Tags: shell-script, awk, quoting, tcsh

I have a script that searches for space characters ' ', exclamation marks '`!`' and dollar signs '`$`' in filenames and replaces each with an underscore '`_`'.  However, it does not handle file names with exclamation marks in them, at all.  Files to be renamed are searched for in the current folder and all sub-folders up to a certain depth (not very relevant here).  Folder names should also be changed in the same way, that's why the depth is staggered.

This is the desired renaming scheme:

```
This is cool!.txt     -->    This_is_cool_.txt
Thank$.log            -->    Thank_.log
Foo 1/Bar 2/a.txt     -->    Foo_1/Bar_2/a.txt
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
  
foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 )
    find . -mindepth $n -maxdepth $n -name '*[ $\!]*' | fgrep -v \" | \
    awk '{printf "mv -i -- \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", gensub("!","\\\\\!","g",$0), gensub(" ","_","g",gensub("\\$","\\\\$","g",gensub("!","\\\\\!","g",$0)))}' | tcsh -cf
end
```

I have varied the number of backslashes '`\`' before both exclamation marks but to no effect.  Error messages may look like this (even number of backslashes):

```
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\!' treated as plain `!'
```

or the shell script (apparently) opens an interactive shell?!  Sometimes nothing happens at all (I suppose when there are too many backslashes in the first argument to `mv` and the file is not found).

PS: As you can see I excluded files with a double quote '`"`' in them because I also could not get those to work, either.  If you could suggest how to handle those as well, all the better!

Comment: Did you try with exactly 4 backslashes? Also, are you open to other shells? [t]csh is a notoriously bad tool for scripting.

Comment: @terdon Thanks, 4 is one of those even cases with `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence '\!' treated as plain '!'`. I did try `| bash` but that did not work either somehow. If you have an answer with a different shell I am very open to it, though!

Comment: Why do you have the loop from 1 to 8 for `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`? Is it only to avoid errors caused by renaming directories before possibly renaming files in them? Or do you want to exclude depth >8?

Comment: Don't write [t]csh scripts - [google "csh why not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not).

Comment: @Bodo I wish to rename `Folder 1/Folder 12/File name.txt` to `Folder_1/Folder_12/File_name.txt` and it works by staggering the depths.

Comment: @EdMorton There will always be reasons not to use one shell but another and I would expect a search for "ksh why not" and "bash why not" also to turn up results (untested). I do like some things in (t)csh not available in other shells (and learned its programming 30 years ago). Having said that I do know quoting is not one of the things tcsh does a lot better than other shells.

Comment: No, that would not turn up any results advising you not to use those shells for writing scripts because those and other bourne-derived shells are designed for writing scripts, unlike [t]csh which is designed for interactive use, not for writing scripts. Hence the fairly large amount of available documentation on why not to use [t]csh for writing scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton Point taken. I prefer `tcsh` in interactive mode. Perhaps I need to switch for scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier just to call the `mv` directly rather than synthesising the command in `awk` and piping it to a shell

```
#!/bin/bash
#
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 8 -type f -name '*[ !$]*' -execdir
    bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f//[ !$]/_}"; done' _ {} +
```

This version renames files but not directories (as stated in the question). If you actually meant to rename directories too, use this variant,

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 8 -depth -name '*[ !$]*' -execdir
    bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f//[ !$]/_}"; done' _ {} +
```

In both cases remove `echo` when you're happy the command is going to do what you expect. Use `mv -i` for interactive renames. The underscore in the `bash -c '...' _ {}` becomes the "name" of the code running in the subshell. It's mapped to `$0` and will be used for reporting code errors (if any), so you could put `bash` there or even `subshell` - it's just a label.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the detail that folder names may contain spaces etc. which should also be replaced. That's why I counted up the the depths separately in find.

Comment: Please explain the underscore `_` before the braces `{}` - is that some `bash` or `find` magic not found in the respective manuals?

Comment: I never want to overwrite files non-interactively and do not want to restrict file names (not to start with a dash/minus) so I use `mv -i --` - I suppose this could be changed here?

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation! The script works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

This script assumes you don't want to limit the depth for `find` and that you want to replace all characters  `$!"'` with `_`.

As the question doesn't contain information about the operating systems or the specific version of the tools, I try rely on POSIX specification only and not to require specific versions like GNU.

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -depth -name '*[ $!"]*' | while IFS= read -r file
do
   dir="${file%/*}"
   newname="$(echo "${file##*/}" | tr ' $!"' '____')"
   echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"
done
```

The script only slightly tested. If it prints the correct `mv` commands remove the `echo`.

Explanation:

`find . -depth`... makes sure the files are printed before the directory if both contain characters to be replaced. This way we will rename the files first, then the parent directory.

The parent directory name is separated with `dir="${file%/*}`"` and left unchanged.

The file name (or last directory name) is extracted and changed with `newname="$(echo "${file##*/}" | tr ' $!"' '____')"`.

---

**Further improvements**

To handle other "strange" characters in file names it is be better to call the code in the loop body directly from `find`'s `-exec` action like in [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653598/330217).

```
find . -depth -name '*[ $!"]*' -exec sh -c 'for file in "$@" ; do dir="${file%/*}" ; newname="$(echo "${file##*/}" | tr '\'' $!"'\'' "____")" ; echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"; done' _ {} +
```

See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Using `-execdir` as in the other answer would avoid splitting file name and parent directory, but this action is not defined by POSIX.

It is possible to replace the `echo`... `|tr`... combination with a replacement by the shell using something like `"${newname//[ $!\"]/_}"`.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for why not to write the find+loop that way and the correct way to do it instead.